# Hand cursor not showing up in windows 10 using kinect 2

Tags: c#

i am using xbox one to developo my app in windows 10 using kinect sdk 2.0 .The problem is Hand cursor not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

After a couple hour of research on internet, found nothing :(
but finally I solved the solution posted on many forum. Guys here is the solution.
**"Controls Basics-WPF"** code run without showing any problem on windows 8, we can move around the hand cursor and so on.. but the problem was in windows 10. no hand cursor no fun at all... just extra work to solved out the problem. i was about to install windows 8 as i am working at Kinect Fitting Room APP in WPF.
but thank God finally I solved out the problem and thought to help out you guys.

A little Magic trick. Its already in the app but we never tried it :D
In Debug or Release mode select either x86 or any cpu, no problem at all.

Just go to "**Engagement and Cursor Setting**" in the app. leave just first option of Engagement style which is set by default. the first option for Engagement style is not working at all in windows 10 (system hand open/ still).
select option Manual (hand over head) or (hand on screen) and there we can get our hand cursor working exactly as in windows 8.
and the magic works :D
Glad to help who are still stuck.